# function does not execute bonded to click event is not executed 100% of the time

Tags: angular

I have a angular material autocomplete input that works with addresses that calls a custom function upon click. However *fillAddress* function is not executed 100% of the time the span element is clicked executing the default autocomplete behavior which I want to avoid at all cost.

This is my html template

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput
                   #autoCompleteAddress
                   class="full-width"
                   placeholder="Address"
                   [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                   formControlName="inputAddress">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let address of addresses" [value]="address.full_address">
                <span (click)="fillAddress(address.full_address, address.address_id); $event.stopPropagation();">{{ address.full_address }}</span>
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.inputAddress" class="alert alert-danger">
              {{ formErrors.inputAddress }}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

This is my function

```
fillAddress(fullAddress, address_id) {
    const strs = fullAddress.split(', ').reverse();

    const postcode = strs[0].split(' ').reverse()[0];
    const state = strs[0].split(' ').reverse().slice(1).reverse().join(' ');
    const city = strs[1];
    const address = strs.splice(2).reverse().join(', ');

    this.ereturnForm.get('inputState').setValue(state);
    this.ereturnForm.get('inputPostalcode').setValue(postcode);
    this.ereturnForm.get('inputCity').setValue(city);
    this.ereturnForm.get('inputAddress').setValue(address);

    this.address_id = address_id;

    this.autoCompleteAddress.closePanel();
}
```

QUESTION: Any idea why fillAddress is not executed every time I click the span element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option 
       (click)="fillAddress(address.full_address, address.address_id); 
                $event.stopPropagation();" 
       *ngFor="let address of addresses" [value]="address.full_address">
    <span>{{ address.full_address }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

try adding the click handler on the `<mat-option>` instead

Comment: also the span tag is not needed in your template